# slick при загрузке показывает все слайды

Tags: css, slick.js

Здрасти, слайдер slick http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ , при загрузке страницы показывает сразу все слайды, и только потом сварачиваеться, выглядит очень не красиво. Пробовал через ксс поправить это дело но не помогает ибо даже если прописать враперу display:none; лаг все равно происходит и только потом слайдер исчезает, есть ли какие нибудь идеи ?

Comment: <code>.middle__slider_item{display: none ;}
  .middle__slider_item:first-child{display: block ;}
  .slick-initialized .middle__slider_item{display: block ;}</code>

Comment: .middle__slider_item{display: none ;}
  .middle__slider_item:first-child{display: block ;}
  .slick-initialized .middle__slider_item{display: block ;}
Помог вот такой код если кому интересно, мы делаем дисплей нон всем слайдам кроме первого, а при инициализации показываем все

Comment: Тоже с этим столкнулась.  Спасибо, ваш код помог!